# I can't save to SharedPreferences after I have cleared SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

There are 2 activity in my project. One is SearchActivity.java and another is Result.java.
I use sharedPreferences in Result.java to save result, but I will not need to save all the time so I cleared ShraedPreferences in SearchActivity is created. And then trying to save result to shardPreferences in Result.java, but sharedPreferences does not save the result.
If I did not clear sharedPrefences in SearchActivity, I can save my result in SharedPreferences.

Thanks,

SearchActivity.java

```
//clear old all of old data in SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.DEFAUL_SHARE_DATA, 0);
pref.edit().clear().commit();
```

Result.java

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences= mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.DEFAUL_SHARE_DATA, 0);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(String.valueOf(txtImage.getId()), txtImage.getText().toString());    
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow your `commit` in `SearchActivity` is getting executed the last. See this notes on the [behavior of `commit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) of `SharedPreferences`

If you have 2 instances where you hold references to the same editor, the last one wins.

In which activity life cycle method are you calling clear in `SearchActivity`, may be that method is getting called again. Its probably on the activity back stack.

Why not move the clearing of old data to the `Result.java` beginning (may be in start of `onCreate`)

Comment: thanks for answer me, why I saved the result to sharedpreferences is I don't like to user to search again that they have already searched or if they pressed back unintentionally. I think that clear and commit sharedpreferences in onCreate will clear the result and I can not show the last results that they searched.

Comment: what is the method name where you call `clear` in searchActivity..is it oncreate ? one option is to enclose the `clear` with if statement `if (newsearch) pref.edit().clear().commit();` to make sure it doesn't call `clear` by mistake of activity life cycle.